# broom::tidy not working with purrr::map_dfr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, broom

I am trying to create a dataframe that contains tidy results from `broom` package for Wilcox's tests. I have been able to write code that runs this test for all grouping variables and creates a list column containing results from these tests. Now I want to use `purrr` to tidy results for each test result and combine them into a single dataframe, but this doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why.

Here is a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# converting iris dataframe to long format
iris_long <- datasets::iris %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data = ., id = dplyr::row_number(x = Species)) %>%
  tidyr::gather(
    data = .,
    key = "condition",
    value = "value",
    Sepal.Length:Petal.Width,
    convert = TRUE,
    factor_key = TRUE
  ) %>%
  tidyr::separate(
    col = "condition",
    into = c("part", "measure"),
    sep = "\\.",
    convert = TRUE
  ) %>%
  tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

# running Wilcox test on each level of factors Species and measure
results_df <- iris_long %>%
  mutate_if(.tbl = ., .predicate = is.character, .funs = as.factor) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(.data = ., Species, measure) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = .) %>% # running two-sample Wilcoxon tests on each individual group with purrr
  dplyr::mutate(results = data %>% purrr::map(
    .x = .,
    .f = ~ stats::wilcox.test(
      formula = value ~ part,
      mu = 0,
      alternative = "two.sided",
      conf.level = 0.95,
      na.action = na.omit,
      conf.int = TRUE,
      data = (.)
    )
  )
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(.data = ., results)

# check the newly created list column containing results from 6 combinations
results_df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   results    
#>   <list>     
#> 1 <S3: htest>
#> 2 <S3: htest>
#> 3 <S3: htest>
#> 4 <S3: htest>
#> 5 <S3: htest>
#> 6 <S3: htest>
# so the function was executed for all groups

# check tidied results for first group
broom::tidy(x = results_df$results[[1]])
#>    estimate statistic      p.value conf.low conf.high
#> 1 -3.500078         0 5.515865e-18 -3.60004 -3.400007
#>                                              method alternative
#> 1 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction   two.sided

# creating a dataframe by tidying results from all results in results_df list
purrr::map_dfr(.x = results_df,
               .f = ~ broom::tidy(x = .),
               .id = "group")
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
#> Error in names(object) <- nm: 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify this instead:

```
.x = results_df$results
```

---

If you are interested with another approach, you can shorten your code using a split.

```
iris_long %>% 
  split(list(.$Species, .$measure)) %>% 
  map_dfr(~wilcox.test(value ~ part, 
                       na.action = na.omit, 
                       conf.int = TRUE, 
                       data = .x) %>% broom::tidy())
```